# Cannot bind BlobProperties in Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am trying to create the following Azure Function in C#:

```
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("container/{name}.png", Connection = "StorageConn")]Stream myBlob, string name, Uri uri, BlobProperties properties, TraceWriter log)
```

but for some reason I keep receiving this error:

> A ScriptHost error has occurred
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'TriggerSaveImgReference.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind parameter 'properties' to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobProperties'.
>
> Error indexing method 'TriggerSaveImgReference.Run'
>
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'TriggerSaveImgReference.Run'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind parameter 'properties' to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.BlobProperties'.

According to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob

I should be able to use `BlobProperties` properties in my binding expression. Am I misunderstanding it? How do I get the `BlobProperties`?

I am using:

```
WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.5.0
Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions version 1.0.2
```

and the target .NET framework is 4.6.1

Comment: Works like charm for me. Could you add the NuGet references and versions  that you use to the question?

Comment: Sure thing - I added them to my post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove the explicit reference to `WindowsAzure.Storage` package.

`Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` has dependency on `7.x` version of it, so your `8.x` version conflicts.

Maybe upgrade `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to `1.0.6` too, although I guess it doesn't matter in your case.

Comment: You are not 100% right, but close :)

It did NOT help to remove the reference to WindowsAzure.Storage, because I was referencing another Class library, which was still using WindowsAzure.Storage version 8.x.

I guess I will have to wait for Microsoft to release a version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions which is not tied to version 7.x of WindowsAzure.Storage OR downgrade the nuget package in my other class library.

*EDIT* I will mark your answer as the solution anyways, since you brought me in the right direction and you are really close to the actual reason.